# Propagation of error for an integral using Leibnitz' rule

Tags: error-propagation, leibniz-integral-rule

I'm computing integrals $u_i$, where
$$u_i = \int_a^b s^i G(s) ds$$
and $a$ and $b$ are constants.

Now I want to estimate the error in $u_i$; I have estimates for the error $\sigma_G$ of $G$, and there is no error in $s$.

Using Leibniz' rule for differentiation under the integral
$${du_i \over dG} = \int_a^b {\partial(s^iG)\over \partial G}ds$$
and since $\displaystyle {\partial(s^iG)\over \partial G}=s^i$,
$${du_i \over dG} = \int_a^b s^i ds = \ln(b)-\ln(a){\rm \ \ if\ }i=-1{\rm,\ else\ }{1\over i+1}(b^{i+1}-a^{i+1})$$
I want to apply the propagation of error approximation
$$\sigma_{u_i}^2\approx \sigma^2_G\left({\partial u_i \over \partial G}\right)^2 $$
so I used $\displaystyle {du_i \over dG}$ for $\displaystyle{\partial u_i \over \partial G}$. I think there is something wrong with this derivation, since numerical tests do not agree with the result calculated from the above.
Can anyone see why this derivation is wrong, or inapplicable?

**Edit:** The form of Leibnitz' rule I am using is
$${d\over dx}\left(\int_{f(x)}^{g(x)} h(x,t)\;dt\right) = g^\prime(x)h\bigl(x,g(x)\bigr)-f^\prime(x)h(x,f(x))+\int_{f(x)}^{g(x)} {\partial h\over \partial x}(x,t)\;dt$$ Since $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are the constants $a$ and $b$, all but the final term on the RHS vanish. I don't see any ambiguity in the meaning of the partial derivative in this term.

Comment: $G$ depends on $s$ so you cannot apply the rule as is. What does having an error estimate for $G$ mean exactly, since it's not a constant? How do you compute $G$ in the first place?

Comment: G is computed numerically (from experimental data). Its error estimate comes from different ways of measuring it. Sorry, I don't understand your comment about the rule not being applicable.

Comment: You are applying the rule as if $G$ was a constant, but in reality you are performing a numerical integration procedure which sums the integrand at certain points by using a rule (trapezoidal rule, or spline for example). The uncertainty in the final quantity depends on your numerical integration method.

Comment: Which rule? $G$ isn't being treated as a constant in Leibitz, nor in the propagation-of-error eqn. Although I do, in fact, do the integration to calculate $u_i$ numerically, I don't see that being relevant in determining a way to estimate $\sigma_{u_i}$ from $\sigma_G$.

Comment: Well, you can't take a derivative in the way you show above, it has to be promoted to a functional derivative. Using the discreteness of your measurement would yield a result that is easier to interpret mathematically- making G(s) a continuous time variable means you are dealing a stochastic process, which is subtle in general.

Comment: See the edit I added. If I am doing this wrong, perhaps you can show me how to do it correctly.  Why should the method I use to determine $G$ matter? I'd like to solve this for a continuous function $G$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I will consider evaluating the integral by discretizing at prescribed intervals according to the information provided in an edit, considering the values of $G$ as Gaussian random variables and computing the variance of the resulting sum as a function of the number of points in the interval $N$.

Assuming that $G(s)$ is distributed as noted above, we note that with the discretization presented in the comments the integral is be approximated by the quantity

$$ I_N(a,b)=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\left[(x_k)^n G(x_k)+(x_{k+1})^n G(x_{k+1})\right](x_{k+1}-x_k)$$

with $x_k=a(b/a)^{k/N}$. This can be rewritten explicitly as

$$ I_N(a,b)=\frac{1}{2}\left(a^{n+1} G(a)\left(\left(b/a \right)^{1/N}-1 \right)+b^{n+1}\left(-\left(b/a\right)^{-1/N}+1\right) G(b)+\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}G(x_k)(a(b/a)^{k/N})^{n+1}((b/a)^{1/N}-(b/a)^{-1/N})\right)$$

We now use the result that the variable $U=\sum_k r_k G_k$ is Gaussian with variance $\sum_k(\sigma_{G_k}^2r_k^2)$ to compute the variance

$$\frac{\sigma^2_{I_N}}{\sigma_G^2}=\frac{a^{2n+2}}{4}\left(\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^{\frac{1}{N}}-1\right)^2+\frac{b^{2n+2}}{4}\left(-\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^{-\frac{1}{N}}+1\right)^2+\frac{1}{4}\left(\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^{1/N}-\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^{-1/N}\right)^2\left[\frac{b^{2n+2}-a^{2n+2}}{(b/a)^{2n+2/N}-1}-a^{2n+2}\right]$$

For large $N$, we find that the variance tends to zero, with leading contribution

$$\frac{\sigma^2_{I_N}}{\sigma_G^2}=\frac{\ln(b/a)}{N}\left(\frac{b^{2n+2}-a^{2n+2}}{2n+2}\right)+\mathcal{O}(1/N^2)$$

The last two expressions are only valid for $n\neq - 1$. In order to obtain a valid formula for $n=-1$, we take the limit $n\to - 1$ of the above and we find

$$\frac{\sigma^2_{I_N}}{\sigma_G^2}=\frac{1}{4}\left(\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^{\frac{1}{N}}-1\right)^2+\frac{1}{4}\left(-\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^{-\frac{1}{N}}+1\right)^2+\frac{N-1}{4}\left(\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^{1/N}-\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^{-1/N}\right)^2$$

and in the large $N$ limit

$$\frac{\sigma^2_{I_N}}{\sigma_G^2}=\frac{\ln^2 b/a}{N}+\mathcal{O}(1/N^2)$$

We observe that:

1. The variance tending to zero as $1/N$ is justified by a slight generalization of the Central Limit Theorem. The effect should persist even for non-Gaussian variables.
2. It is impossible to write the variance simply as an integral- note that the sum contains a term that is quadratic in the spacing $\sim\sum(x_{k+1}-x_k)^2$, which is not directly amenable to a Riemann integral treatment. In fact, this object has completely different properties, in that it's explicit value depends on the discretization scheme chosen. It's an interesting exercise to partition the interval linearly instead of logarithmically to see that it produces a different result.
3. Both results for finite and large $N$ agree very well with the numerical results cited below in the comments.

Comment: Using the above equation for $\sigma_{u_n}$ gives results that are wildly different from my numerical results. I have calculated the latter two different ways: by Monte Carlo using 500 trials, and by propagation of error from quadrature to evaluate the integral. These two ways agree. For example, when $n=0$, $a=1.5 \times 10^{-14}$ and $b=6.8 \times 10^{-11}$, your equation gives $\sigma_{u_0}^2/\sigma_G^2=6.8\times 10^{-11}$, while my numerical methods give $1.9 \times 10^{-27}$.

Comment: I'm afraid that this discrepancy is generated by the way you sample the interval. If you're willing to provide more details on the sampling procedure and how the comparison is made between the two different methods (in fact I'm not sure I understand how you compute an error based on a Monte Carlo approximation since all you got is discrete measurements of G(s) to my understanding) I'll rewrite the answer.

Comment: For the MC test, I took $G$ to be a constant, 5 (so I could calculate everything exactly). I did 500 trials: each trial consisted of generating 1000 points of $G(s)$. Each $G(s)$ had a value of 5 + $x$, where $x$ was a random variate with a mean of 0 and std dev of 0.1. I took $s$ as a fixed array (equally log-spaced). I then integrated the 1000 points of $s^iG$ over the range of $s$, i e $a$ to $b$, using quadrature (trapezoidal rule) to get samples of $u_i$. Finally, I computed the mean and std dev of the population of $u_i$.

Comment: For the propagation-of-error method, I wrote the approximation of the integral as a sum, using the trapezoidal rule. This sum simplifies to a sum $a_iG_i$ + plus a term at each endpoint. Because the $s_i$ have no error, the $a_i$ are constants, so for each term $j$ in the sum and the endpoints, $\sigma_{term_j}^2=a_j^2\sigma_{G_j}^2$. So $\sigma_{u_i}^2\approx \Sigma a_j^2\sigma_{G_j}^2$

Comment: My numerical results do not agree with your second attempt, either, although they are not so far off. For $n=-1, 0, 1, 2, 3$ my values (method next answer) are $7.0442\times10^{-2},1.9376\times10^{-23},4.4741\times10^{-44},1.3776\times10^{-64},4.7719\times10^{-85}$. Using your eqn, the corresponding values are  $---, 2.9156\times10^{-23},9.0146\times10^{-44},3.4839\times10^{-64},1.4541\times10^{-84}$. Sorry I forgot to mention $n=-1$.

Comment: There was a typo, which I corrected. Now all of the methods agree with one another.

Comment: Great, and now my numerical results agree with yours, to about 1% or better (for $N=1002$). Thanks for taking all the time to work on this.

Comment: No problem! Don't forget to upvote and click the checkmark if this answers your question :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my derivation for the propagation-of-error method. Eqn (3) is the trapezoidal rule. There is no restriction on the spacing of $s$.
$$\eqalignno{
\mu_i &\approx \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} {\textstyle{1\over 2}}( s^i_j G_j + s^i_{j+1} G_{j+1}) ( s_{j+1}- s_j) &(3)\cr
 &= {\textstyle{1\over 2}} s^i_1 G_1 ( s_2- s_1)
  + {\textstyle{1\over 2}} \left(\sum_{j=2}^{n-1} s^i_j G_j ( s_{j+1}- s_{j-1})\right)
   + {\textstyle{1\over 2}} s^i_n G_n ( s_n- s_{n-1})&(17a)\cr
 &= \sum_{j=1}^n a_j G_j&(17b)\cr
}$$
where the coefficients $a_j$ are independent of $G_j$, and defined by
$$a_j =
\cases{
{\textstyle{1\over 2}} s^i_1 ( s_2- s_1) &if $j=1$\cr
\cr
{\textstyle{1\over 2}} s^i_n ( s_n- s_{n-1}) &if $j=n$\cr
\cr
{\textstyle{1\over 2}} s^i_j ( s_{j+1}- s_{j-1}) &otherwise\cr
}$$
So, since ${\displaystyle\partial(a_jG_j)\over \displaystyle\partial G_j} = a_j$,
$$\eqalignno{
\sigma^2_{\mu_i} &= \sum_1^n a_j^2\sigma_{G_j}^2 & (19)
}$$

Comment: Numerical results for the ratio $\sigma_{\mu_i}^2/\sigma_G^2$ for constant $\sigma_{G_j}$ are in my last comment to the previous answer.